# Groovy List Conversion

Tags: groovy

I'm having an issue in groovy trying to figure out how to convert a single item to a list.  I have an incoming variable `params.contacts`, which could be a single value (e.g. 14) or it could be an array of values (e.g. 14, 15).  I want to always turn it into a list.  Previously, I was simply saying `params.contacts.toList()`, but this code fails when it's a single item. It would take a value of 14 and divide it into a list of [1, 4].

Is there a simple, elegant way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 8):

One easy way, put it in a list and flatten it:

```
def asList(orig) {
    return [orig].flatten()
}

assert [1, 2, 3, 4] == asList([1, 2, 3, 4])
assert ["foo"] == asList("foo")
assert [1] == asList(1)
```

One problem with this is that it'll completely flatten things, so it's not a good approach as it'll flatten lists within your list:

```
assert [[1, 2], [3, 4]] == asList([[1, 2], [3, 4]])  // fails!
```

Another way would be to use the type system to your advantage:

```
def asList(Collection orig) {
    return orig
}

def asList(orig) {
    return [orig]
}

assert [1, 2, 3, 4] == asList([1, 2, 3, 4])
assert ["foo"] == asList("foo")
assert [1] == asList(1)
assert [[1, 2], [3, 4]] == asList([[1, 2], [3, 4]])  // works!
```

Here, we let the type system do all the heavy lifting for us.  If we've already got a collection, just return it.  Otherwise, turn it into a list.  Tricks like this from Java are still available to us in groovy, and we shouldn't completely throw them out when they're the right thing for the problem.

Comment: Confirmed that assert [14] == asList(14) is true. +1